# how to calculate number of jobs if result is given

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If 1996 jobs per week give you 3.34 productivity
How many jobs per week are required to achieve 3.64 productivity?

Comment: It depends on the relationship of jobs per week and productivity. Do you have any further info? Maybe a first attempt?

Comment: $1996\cdot\frac{3.64}{3.34}$

Comment: Thank you @barakmanos I did the same way but there was another method I tried: `1 job productivity = 3.34/1996 = 0.0017` and `3.64/0.0017 = 2,141.1765 - 1996 = 145.1765 jobs` but it was invalid as 146*0.0017=0.2482+3.34=3.5882' which is NOT 3.64

Comment: You are not using enough significant digits to get the accuracy you want. There are only two significant digits in $0.0017$ (the zeros on the left don't count). You will be lucky if even the first two digits of your answer are correct after dividing by such a number. A better approximation is $3.34/1996 = 0.0016733$.

Answer (score 0):

$1996/3.34=x/3.64$
$3.34x=1996*3.64$
$3.34x=7265.44$
$x=2,175.28$ jobs

Hope that helped.